# where is a model's attribute defined?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

When I do `$user = \App\Models\User::findOrFail(512)` in `php artisan tinker` I get something like this back:

```
=> App\Models\User {#4586
     userID: 512,
     userName: "neubert",
     legalFirst: "Neu",
     firstName: "Neu",
     lastName: "Bert",
...
   }
```

Notably, `has_ability_to_view_users_timeclock_reports` is not present in what's returned. And yet when I do `$user->has_ability_to_view_users_timeclock_reports` I got a non-null value back (I get true back).

My question is...  how might I found out where `has_ability_to_view_users_timeclock_reports` is defined? It's not defined in the `App\Models\User` model. When I do `grep -r has_ability_to_view_users_timeclock_reports .` in the code base I see it being used but never actually defined.

It's not a column in the table that `\App\Models\User` corresponds to.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a `public function getHasAbilityToViewUsersTimeclockReportsAttribute()` (or similar) method in your `User.php` model? It might be an [Accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators). Or it could be defined in a trait, etc.; there are lots of ways to add properties to Models 

Comment: This looks like a trait for handling permissions on the user model

Comment: Or more accurately, [Accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor); their syntax has been updated in more recent versions of Laravel to help with this exact issue 

Comment: it can be both, an accessor method defined in a trait. it can also be an overload over the __get magic method used by eloquent model. better look for functions with keyword `HasAbilityTo`

Answer (score 0):

The output for models in tinker is determined here https://github.com/laravel/tinker/blob/97357b4ebec94d728847bff80362a4eb9f64ede0/src/TinkerCaster.php#L103

You can `dd()` your model to see more info